# apache localhost pages serving larger viewport width than the actual

Tags: apache, localhost, viewport

I am puzzled. My screen resolution is 1366 x 768.  I am a web developer and my local dev environment is apache. My default browser is chrome. Everything were fine till a few days back. Now I am experiencing a strange behavior. Every web page coming through the localhost route is showing a viewport width 1515 instead of the actual 1366. I cannot figure out what is the problem. To clarify a little bit, the HTML page shown in the code below(it is a w3school example) when opened through localhost give the viewport width 1515. When opened by double clicking (That is NOT using localhost) it gives the right 1366. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display this window's height and width 
(NOT including     toolbars and scrollbars).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The innerWidth and innerHeight properties 
are not     supported in IE8 and earlier.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + 
"<br>Height: " + h;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me add: All web pages, from the net, including my own from remote servers behave properly. The problem is ONLY on localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have some browser zoom applied? Chrome remembers the zoom-level on a per-domain basis. Try clearing it with ctrl-0.